# Where can I see ''terms of service'' on GCP console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am finding it difficult to locate the 'terms of service' document in my gcp account.

Comment: There is no specific part of the console that cover this, instead you should look into GCP [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/terms)

Comment: Thankyou. Just wanted to confirm, is the https://cloud.google.com/terms agreement same for all the customers/organizations?